# Android Gradle Jacoco: offline instrumentation for integration tests

Tags: android, gradle, offline, jacoco, test-coverage

we are building an Android app which is tested by using Appium. Now I would like to see the test coverage of our Appium tests.
I think this is possible, because Jacoco supports offline instrumentation (http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html).

And even the documentation of the jacoco gradle plugin says:

> While all tasks of type Test are automatically enhanced to provide coverage information when the java plugin has been applied, any task that implements JavaForkOptions can be enhanced by the JaCoCo plugin. That is, any task that forks Java processes can be used to generate coverage information.

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

But how do I have to write the build.gradle so our acceptance debug flavor is instrumented and the exec file is written to the Smartphone when the Appium tests are executed or even manual test cases are executed?
Because then I can extract the exec file and send it so SonarQube for further analysis.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed it to get it working and I want to share the solution with you:

enable instrumentation for your buildType and configure SonarQube accordingly
e.g.

```
...
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
...

android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        acceptance {
            applicationId packageName + ".acceptance"
            buildTypes {
                debug {
                    testCoverageEnabled true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "..."
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", sonarDatabaseUrl
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", sonarDatabaseDriverClassName
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", sonarDatabaseUsername
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", sonarDatabasePassword

        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test"
        property "sonar.inclusions", "**/*.java,**/*.xml"
        property "sonar.import_unknown_files", "true"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/acceptance/debug"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/acceptanceDebug"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/testAcceptanceDebugUnitTest.exec"
        // see steps below on how to get that file:
        property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "build/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec"

        property "sonar.projectKey", projectKey
        property "sonar.projectName", projectName
        property "sonar.projectVersion", appVersionName
    }
}
```

add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
 android:name=".util.CoverageDataDumper"
 tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="org.example.DUMP_COVERAGE_DATA"/>
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

CoverageDataDumper should look like that:

```
public class CoverageDataDumper extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( CoverageDataDumper.class );

   @Override
   public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
      try {
         Class
            .forName( "com.vladium.emma.rt.RT" )
            .getMethod( "dumpCoverageData", File.class, boolean.class, boolean.class )
            .invoke( null,
               new File( App.getContext().getExternalFilesDir( null ) + "/coverage.ec" ),
               true, // merge
               false // stopDataCollection
            );
      }
      catch ( Exception e ) {
         LOG.error( "Error when writing coverage data", e );
      }
   }
}
```

Then run your Appium test cases with the acceptance flavor app (with instrumented classes). Before you call "Reset App" or "Close Application" make sure to call the following methods (just a draft, but I think you get the idea):

```
// intent is "org.example.DUMP_COVERAGE_DATA"
public void endTestCoverage( String intent ) {
  if ( driver instanceof AndroidDriver ) {
     ((AndroidDriver) driver).endTestCoverage( intent, "" );
  }
}
public void pullCoverageData( String outputPath ) {
  String coverageFilePath = (String) appiumDriver.getCapabilities().getCapability( "coverageFilePath" );
  if ( coverageFilePath != null ) {
     byte[] log = appiumDriver.pullFile( coverageFilePath );
     MobileAppLog.writeLog( new File( outputPath ), log );
  }
  else {
     throw new AppiumLibraryNonFatalException(
        "Tried to pull the coverage data, but the coverageFilePath wasn't specified." );
  }
}
```

outputPath could be for example: /sdcard/Android/data/org.example.acceptance/files/coverage.ec

Now the Jacoco data is written to the Smartphone. Next we need to download that file. You can use

```
appiumDriver.pullFile( logFilePath );
```

Now you need to copy the file "jacoco-it.exec" (which should always be *appended* when you pull the file) into build/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec see gradle.build above and run

```
gradlew sonarRunner
```

In SonarQube add the Integration Test Coverage Widget and you should see now some values...

**Unfortunately code coverage won't work if you are using retrolambda (as we do). Retrolambda will generate anonymous classes which are not part of the source files - so SonarQube cannot match them correctly and displays a much lower code coverage than it actually is. If someone finds a solution for that, I would be very happy :-)**

Comment: Am I missing something, or are you using both emma and jacoco here? I have a similar issue so this answer is highly interesting - but am unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding broadcast receiver to the application you test! (you can add the receiver only to debug folder cause no need it for to exist in main source)

```
 public class CoverageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String EXEC_FILE_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/coverage.exec";
    private static final String TAG = "CoverageJacoco";
    private static final String BROADCAST_RECEIVED_MESSAGE = "EndJacocoBroadcast broadcast received!";
    private static final String EMMA_CLASS = "com.vladium.emma.rt.RT";
    private static final String EMMA_DUMP_METHOD = "dumpCoverageData";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, BROADCAST_RECEIVED_MESSAGE);
        Class.forName(EMMA_CLASS)
                .getMethod(EMMA_DUMP_METHOD, File.class, boolean.class,
                        boolean.class)
                .invoke(null, new File(EXEC_FILE_PATH), true,
                        false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

In manefist add (you can add this debug folder so it won't exist in main source)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application>

        <receiver android:name=".CoverageReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

In the build.gradle of the application I added

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.4+"
}

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.11"

    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true

        }
    }
```

you build your application as debug, than install and run it.

send broadcast through ADB "adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.action" to create coverage.exec 
pull coverage from device - adb pull /mnt/sdcard/coverage.exec

after you run this you need to create the coverage from the file

```
   **
 * This task is used to create a code coverage report via the Jcoco tool.
 */
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    def coverageSourceDirs = [
            'src/main/java',               
    ]
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generates Jacoco coverage reports"
    reports {
        csv.enabled false
        xml{
            enabled = true
            destination "${buildDir}/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
        }
        html{
            enabled true
            destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
        }
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*',
                       '**/*Activity*.*',
                       '**/*Fragment*.*'
            ]
    )
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('build/coverage.exec')
}
```

this task is one way to create coverage files
in coverageSourceDirs add all the locations of your applicaiton source code, so it will know which code to take and create coverage based on them
executionData is the location where you put the coverage.exec you pulled from the device

Run the task 
the files will created for html and xml you can also add csv (notice it will be create in the build folder of the application)!

Need to know, you must run the task against the same code you built your application debug version