# Missing jacoco.exec file when using jacoco offline instrumentation with Powermock

Tags: maven, powermock, jacoco, powermockito, jacoco-maven-plugin

Despite apparently this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983740/unable-to-get-jacoco-to-work-with-powermockito-using-offline-instrumentation/27769038#27769038) showed a solution to using powermock and jacoco, I haven't been able to make it work in a pretty simple project ([available on GitHub](https://github.com/codependent/jacoco-powermock)).

In my case, the test executes correctly but the jacoco.exec file is missing so jacoco doesn't check coverage.

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareOnlyThisForTest(Util.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("org.jacoco.agent.rt.*")
public class UtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testSay() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util.class);
        Mockito.when(Util.say(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("hello:mandy");
        Assert.assertEquals("hello:mandy", Util.say("sid"));
    }

}
```

**Util.java**

```
public class Util {

    private Util() {}

    public static String say(String s) {
        return "hello:"+s;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.codependent.jacocopower</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-powermock</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <powermock.version>1.5.4</powermock.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**Maven execution trace**, complaining that no jacoco.exec file was found:

```
>> mvn clean verify

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jacoco-powermock 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:instrument (default-instrument) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.codependent.jacoco.UtilTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.239 sec - in com.codependent.jacoco.UtilTest

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:restore-instrumented-classes (default-restore-instrumented-classes) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report (default-report) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target\jacoco-powermock-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:check (default-check) @ jacoco-powermock ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:C:\SoftDesarrollo\6-Workspaces\libertyGecon\jacoco-powermock\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.987s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 21 09:13:55 CET 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/331M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE: ([here on GitHub](https://github.com/codependent/jacoco-powermock/tree/lencalot))**

With the answer provided by Lencalot the jacoco.exec file is generated but the following scenario keeps saying that the ServiceImpl class coverage is 0%:

**ServiceImpl**

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

    public String operation() {
        return Util.say("Hi!");
    }

}
```

**ServiceTest**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Util.class})
public class ServiceTest {

    private Service service = new ServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void testOperation() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util.class);
        Mockito.when(Util.say(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("Bye!");
        Assert.assertEquals("Bye!", service.operation());
    }

}
```

**Trace:**

```
[WARNING] Rule violated for class com.codependent.jacoco.ServiceImpl: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-instrument</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*test*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*test*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Prepare-Jacoco</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*test*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

you can remove Check for now, we can try to get it working with out that first.

Update your Jacoco dependency to look like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make you maven surefire plugin look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

in your properties section Add this as, and change your jacoco Version:

```
<jacoco.version>0.7.5.201505241946</jacoco.version>
<jacoco.outputDir>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</jacoco.outputDir>
```

@codependent Heres an example of why you want to mock.

Lets assume your Util.class has a lot more code, a lot of instantiations and maybe it even touches some server side stuff, hell maybe even its a UI. You don't want to instantiate User.class just to test a single method in some other class called UtilUser.class

```
protected class UtilUser {
    protected UtilUser() {}

    public Boolean checkSay(String s) {
        String expectedString = "hello:" + s;
        String actualString = Util.say(s);

        if (expectedString.equals(actualString){
           return true;
        } else { 
           return false;
        }

    }
}
```

To unit test UtilUser, you want to hit all branches. So in your test you would mock the Util.class, and in one unit test force it to return the correct string, and in another test have it return an incorrect string. You don't care about testing User.class, you know it will behave accordingly or you will have another test to take care of that. For unit testing UtilUser, you can expect Util to either return a correct string or an incorrect string, and you want to test both possibilities.

Theres a time and a place for mocks and they are a great tool to know, but DO NOT think they should be used often. Please refer to the following article, it will give you good insight into when you should use mocks:  [When To Mock](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I had already thought that could be the cause and had even used an absolute URL. However the jacoco.exec file is still missing...

Comment: @codependet Heres somethings I would try and it might give me some more info to be able to help you. If you are using eclipse, try running code coverage locally. Tell me if that is working. one thing I have found is that the default instrument only needs to be run on test files. Try adding `<includes>
        <include>**/*test*</include>
       </includes>` to your default instrument and restore goals configuration. (this will also help with future problems if you are running normal prepare agents).

Comment: @codependent one thing my project also needed when using JaCoCo and Powermock was javassist, try importing that into your maven file dependencies as well.

Comment: I tried adding the `includes` tag but the jacoco.exec file isn't generated either. The project already included javassist as a dependency :-(

Comment: @codependent Alright, I spent a lot of time fighting with powermock/jacoco. So I updated my answer giving you the way my parent pom is configured to run Jacoco with powermock. Try those and let me know how it goes. Also In your test change to this `@PrepareForTest({Util.class})` and get rid of `@PowerMockIgnore("org.jacoco.agent.rt.*")`

Comment: Hi again. I changed the config following your answer and now I can see the jacoco.exec file being correctly generated. The next thing I did was adding the check execution tag to verify the minimum coverage but it finds a 0 line coverage. I have uploaded the code here: https://github.com/codependent/jacoco-powermock/tree/lencalot Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @codependent Please mark as answer if it helped ;) I don't mind the points so I can get more privileges to help more people. With the project you uploaded you will have 0% coverage. When you mock something, you are not actually testing it, you are forcing it to do something (expected behavior). When you use the `@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)`  SomeClass.class will not give ANY results to unit tests, even if you are just mocking 1 method in it.

Comment: @codependent I'll append something to my answer to show you an example as to why you would want to mock and how it would be useful.

Comment: I get your point about what mocking is really useful for. I'm updating the question with a real scenario like the one you suggested: a service that uses a static class in a method. I want to test the Service coverage, and unfortunately it keeps saying that it's 0%, (!!!)

Comment: @codependent Wheew alright I figured it out, pulled down your project and have been working on it for like 2 hours haha. Alright You need to change the configuration of the Prepare agent to `<exclude>*</exclude>`. and Remove the configurations for the Default instrument and restore instrument. I don't know why, but the `**/*test*` is not picking up your Test class.  It is in my project, but I have no idea why its not in yours.

Comment: @codependent BOOM! figured out why the `**/*test*` was not picking up the test class. Wrong powermock version. please disregard my previous comment. Change your powermock version to `1.6.4` and your code coverage will be showing :)

Comment: You're the man!!. I do appreciate your taking the time to work this out, thanks!!