# Mocking oracle STRUCT class for junit coverage

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

In my project, i am required to call a stored procedure in oracle. This procedure accepts a custom table of objects type which i have created. On java side, i have created implemented type handler and handled passing array type data to procedure.

Everything is working fine from coding point of view :)

Now i need to write junits for the handler class which i have created. This handler calls my util class to get the StructDescriptor, STRUCT objects. Below is the utility class code snippet.

```
Class JDBCUtil {
    public static STRUCT getJDBCDataObject(final StructDescriptor structDescriptor, final Connection con,
      final Object[] params) {
    STRUCT struct = null;
    try {
      struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, con, params);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
    return struct;
  }
}
```

I have both Mockito and PowerMockito libraries in my maven dependency. Below is my test class.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ StructDescriptor.class, ArrayDescriptor.class, STRUCT.class })
public class JDBCUtil Test {

  private JDBCUtil jdbcUtil;

  @Mock
  private OracleConnection connection;

  @Mock
  private StructDescriptor structDescriptor;

  @Mock
  private STRUCT struct;


  @Before
  public void test() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    jdbcUtil = new JDBCUtil();


    Mockito.when(connection.isLogicalConnection()).thenReturn(false);
  }

  @Test
  public void testShouldReturnValidJDBCTypeStructureObject() {
    Object[] objs = new Object[1];
    objs[0] = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
    try {
      //Mockito.when(new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection,     objs)).thenReturn(struct);
      PowerMockito.whenNew(STRUCT.class).withArguments(structDescriptor, connection, objs).thenReturn(struct);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    STRUCT structObj = JDBCProcedureTypeDescriptor.getJDBCDataObject(structDescriptor, connection, objs);
    Assert.assertNotNull(structObj);
  }


}
```

I am trying to mock the object of STRUCT being created in my class but my code always tries to create the object and fails as the connection etc are mock objects and it gives null pointer in **STRUCT<init()>(STRUCT.java:138)**

Though when i add **JDBCUtil** in **@PrepareForTest** annotation, the test case gets executed successfully but eclipse does not show the class being covered at all.

Is there any way i can mock the STRUCT object creation and cover my method by 100%.

Comment: Are you using ECLEmma for your Eclipse IDE code coverage plugin?

Comment: There is a known issue with ECLEmma reporting test coverage from PowerMock.
https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/15

This may be a duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983740/unable-to-get-jacoco-to-work-with-powermockito-using-offline-instrumentation

Comment: *Everything works fine from coding point of view*. No, it doesn't, there are various problems in your code: A) why the empty catch block in your production code? Your current approach screams for NullPointerExceptions later on ..  B) Why catch blocks with trace statements in your test (if your code throws an exception, you probably want your test to **fail** on them?!)

Comment: @GhostCat : A) Thanks for the heads Up. Will add that. B)I am only trying to debug the test right now. Once i am able to get it running correctly, will handle the fail conditions as well.

Comment: Yes, I am using ECLEmma for test coverage check in eclipse. Even with Powermock, the plugin shows the data correctly for other tests, but only when i include JDBCUtil in @PrepareForTests annotation(Class for which i am writing junit), it fails and does not show coverage and without adding it does not work :(.

Answer (score 0):

The question: did you start using Powermock, because you have good reasons to, or more by coincidence?

You see - the problem lies within your code. It is simply written in an **untestable** way. And surprise: the way it is written, it will also affect the testability of each "client" that wants to make use of this method.

The key problem is: you are using **static** here; without any need to do so. What prevents you from renaming your JdbcUtils into "STRUCTFactory" for example? And then, instead of having a static method in there, you just create a normal instance method. And all of a sudden, you don't need PowerMock any more for the static call. If you worry about efficiency (which you shouldn't at this point); you could still use a singleton and attach a STRUCTFactory interface to that.

Next - why do you want to use a mocking framework to check the call to new? In essence, you are testing implementation details. It would be much simpler to write a test that simply calls the factory method (with different parameters), and then do **assertXyz** calls on the STRUCT object that is returned to you.

Meaning:

1. **static** is an abnormality in good OO design; avoiding it helps in many ways; using it forces you to turn to PowerMock.
2. You don't have to test an operation **itself**, it is perfectly fair to check that the result of an operation has the expected properties!

Long story short: there are few reasons to use PowerMock; and many to not do so (the problem with coverage you are facing is one of them). But your code can be easily reworked so that you can fully test it with Mokito - no  super *power* required on top of that. Just by following some simple rules that are known good "OO design" practices in the first place.

If you are interested in "how to create testable" code ... you can turn [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79).

Comment: I have tried to write test for this without static as well. The problem is that when STRUCT class object is created, i uses the input parameters in contructor. Since those objects are mock objects, it fails at some point giving nullpointer. Even if i could find the code for STRUCT class, i can mock that perticular instance which is giving nullpointer. Problem is, test fails while initilizing STRUCT object.

Comment: I checked for the source on google and found https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/okidev/attic/temp/STRUCT.java but the line at which i get the nullpointer isn't matching with the source code in this link. Also i needed to use powermock as i also have used apache commons io FileUtils class. To prevent from actual file transfer in my test cases, i have used powermock.